# How to make a new branch that is reverted from master, and then make pull requested with the branch after new commit after reversion?

Tags: git, pull-request

Bascially, master is A-B-C-D-E. I would like to revert to C. So far, I have done `git checkout -b revertedBranch <C's commit hash>`. I made a change, then commit and push the changes. Will I be able to create a pull request successfully? Essentially, it's going from Head to modified C.
So, revertedBranch will look like C-X. Then the pull request will try to get it to look like A-B-C-D-E-X. Does that work?

Comment: If you want to reach `A-B-C-D-E-X`, why not create commit X directly in a branch containing the whole content of `master`, i.e. `A-B-C-D-E`?

Comment: I'm assuming that by `revert to C`, you mean rewind, go back in the commit history. `revert` in git means creating a new commit which cancels (undo) the changes of a previous commit in the history.

Comment: @Mehdi Yes, correct. I need to make a pull request for this change and have a colleague review it.

Comment: Why do you want to rewind to commit C instead of checking out new branch with same content as `master`?

Comment: @Mehdi the change is to revert to C, then make a change there and push. Can I make a new branch with same content as ```master```, and then revert there, make the change, push the branch and create pull request?

Answer (score 0):

To answer to your question this will work.

As said by several people you should take care of the wording, you are not doing revert here, just forking from a previous commit.

So if you submit your pull request this can lead to:

```
                ---X---   revertedBranch
              /         \
     A---B---C---D---E---Y--- master
```

Y will be the merge commit of your branch into master.
Or if you set up git hub to rebase the PR:

```
     A---B---C---D---E---X'--- master
```

X' is the commit rebased on master